# mongo crashed and now not starting

Tags: linux, mongodb

My mongo was working fine. Today when I tried to open, it gives

```
ubuntu@DELL-PC:/usr/bin$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8
connecting to: test
2016-08-11T13:24:25.600+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-08-11T13:24:25.600+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I moved to /usr/db and tried to open mongod from there using `sudo ./mongod`

```
ubuntu@DELL-PC:/usr/bin$ sudo ./mongod
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=9371 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=DELL-PC
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-08-11T13:26:34.693+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-08-11T13:26:34.719+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2016-08-11T13:26:34.719+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I check I have free hard disk space.

```
ubuntu@DELL-PC:/usr/bin$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           486M  7.5M  478M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        97G   81G   12G  88% /
tmpfs           2.4G   52M  2.4G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           486M   72K  485M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Can someone please suggest what can be the issue here?

What is the location of mongotable which I created earlier. i.e. location of `data/db`

How can I search it in terminal?

Your help much appreciated.

Comment: `exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly your configuration was updated by you hosting provider.  It looks like your default configuration is pointing to the wrong dbpath.  You'll need to update your config file to use the correct path.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/

You can also test by just launching mongod using --dbpath.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't tell mongo what is your database directory, it assumes that it's /data/db. Not /usr/db.

So, with ./mongod --dbpath /usr/db it should start..